# Configuring ElasticClient connection pooling

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am currently updating our elasticsearch code to use the built-in Connection Pooling offered by Nest's IElasticClient. So before we were using

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(connString));
var esClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

and now I want to be able to pass in a configured connection pool (as mentioned in [Nest's docs](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/connecting.html)) like so

```
var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { new Uri(connString});
var config = new ConnectionConfiguration(connectionPool);
                     .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                     .SniffOnStartup(false)
                     .SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var client = new ElasticsearchClient(config);
```

However, they use the raw ElasticsearchClient to do this. Nest's ElasticClient constructor does not offer the ability to pass in a ConnectionConfiguration, only a ConnectionPool.

Does anyone know how to use a ConnectionConfiguration with an ElasticClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Nest.ConnectionSettings` for this. See the code below:

```
var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { new Uri(connString});
var config = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
    .SniffOnStartup(false)
    .SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var client = new ElasticClient(config);
```

Comment: It was right there in front of my nose. Thanks for your help @bsarkar.